# update record against a specific user in user class Parse ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

i have user class in parse and want to update record against specific user in parse.i do not know how i update it.

```
PFUser *user= [PFUser user];

[user whereKey:@"username" equalTo:@"john"];

 user[@"cellNo"]=cell.text;

[user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if(!error)

            {

             ............
            }

        }];
```

But `[user whereKey:@"userName" equalTo:@"john"];` can not be work and error found how i handle it.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error found : no visible @interface for 'PFUser' declares the Selector 'whereKey :equalTo:'

Comment: Did you declare - (void)whereKey:(NString*) equalTo:(NSString *) in PFUser.h ?

Comment: Mahi Basically i don't know how i resolve it. Please write a code....

Comment: Can you try by using - PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is created a user instance. As opposed to querying the user class. PFUser is either pointing to an existing or creating one in your circumstance. This is a common error in the SO community and should have popped up on google had you researched it. The proper way to query the user class in Parse is :

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
```

Then perform the rest of your method.

FYI, another common issue with parse is that devs think they can alter another users info. You can't do that for security reasons, so if your trying to update someone else's info in the user class you won't be able to unless your signed in as that user for current user

Comment: it's means i can change only current user data in parse not anther user reocrd in parse???

Comment: it means you can only change your info and no one else's. If your bob and your trying to change Stevens info you won't be able to. You have to be logged in as Steven to change that info. But first you have to query correctly @ShahbazAkram which is stated above in my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're signed in as John, the following code will work:

```
PFUser *user= [PFUser currentUser];
user[@"cellNo"]=cell.text;
[user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if(!error) {

    }
}];
```

But as @soulshined said, you can't update another user. (One who isn't logged in on the device making the call)

Comment: its means i can change only current user data in parse. Do not change another user data. is it ok????